# Make .swf file full screen on any screen

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I make a .swf file fullscreen by the coding in the .fla file?
`Stage["displayState"]="fullScreen";`
doesn't work

Comment: So you want the .swf file opened with fullscreen as default?

Comment: @jont yes that is what I want

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these commands:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

or

```
fscommand("fullscreen", true);
```

Comment: The first method works fine but there are white borders at the side, any idea on how to solve it? Thank you!